# Junit not running tests in parallel

Tags: java, testing, junit, parallel-processing, spock

I have test:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.parallel.Execution // version 5.9.0
import org.junit.jupiter.api.parallel.ExecutionMode
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll

@Execution(ExecutionMode.CONCURRENT)
class ExampleTest extends Specification {

    @Unroll
    @Execution(ExecutionMode.CONCURRENT)
    def "test1: should get valid #testParam"() {
        System.out.println("FirstParallelUnitTest first() start => " + Thread.currentThread().getName() +
                "  id: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        given:
            def test = testParam
        expect:
            test != null
            System.out.println("FirstParallelUnitTest first() end => " + Thread.currentThread().getName() +
                    "  id: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        where:
            testParam << ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
    }

    @Unroll
    @Execution(ExecutionMode.CONCURRENT)
    def "test2: should get valid #testParam"() {
        System.out.println("FirstParallelUnitTest first() start => " + Thread.currentThread().getName() +
                "  id: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        given:
            def test = testParam
        expect:
            test != null
            System.out.println("FirstParallelUnitTest first() end => " + Thread.currentThread().getName() +
                    "  id: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        where:
            testParam << ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
    }

    @Unroll
    @Execution(ExecutionMode.CONCURRENT)
    def "test3: should get valid #testParam"() {
        System.out.println("FirstParallelUnitTest first() start => " + Thread.currentThread().getName() +
                "  id: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        given:
            def test = testParam
        expect:
            test != null
            System.out.println("FirstParallelUnitTest first() end => " + Thread.currentThread().getName() +
                    "  id: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        where:
            testParam << ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
    }
}
```

I have created `junit-platform.properties` file in `src/test/resources` that contains:

```
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled=true
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default = concurrent
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.classes.default = concurrent
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.strategy=fixed
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.fixed.parallelism=2
```

I have also tried adding `systemProperties` like that in `gradle` file:

```
test {
    testLogging {
        exceptionFormat = 'full'
    }
    useJUnitPlatform()
    systemProperties([
            'junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled': 'true',
            'junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default': 'concurrent',
            'junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.classes.default': 'concurrent',
    ])
}
```

I am using `gradle` version `7.6`.

I added this `junit` test dependencies:

```
testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit5")
testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params")
```

I have also tried adding to `build.gradle` this:

```
subprojects {
    tasks.withType(Test) {
        maxParallelForks = Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors()
    }
}
```

Not divided cause i wanted to see change on `i7-6600U` processor (2 cores).

When running the test i see these logs:

```
FirstParallelUnitTest first() start => Test worker  id: 1
FirstParallelUnitTest first() end => Test worker  id: 1
FirstParallelUnitTest first() start => Test worker  id: 1
FirstParallelUnitTest first() end => Test worker  id: 1
FirstParallelUnitTest first() start => Test worker  id: 1
FirstParallelUnitTest first() end => Test worker  id: 1
FirstParallelUnitTest first() start => Test worker  id: 1
FirstParallelUnitTest first() end => Test worker  id: 1
FirstParallelUnitTest first() start => Test worker  id: 1
FirstParallelUnitTest first() end => Test worker  id: 1
FirstParallelUnitTest first() start => Test worker  id: 1
FirstParallelUnitTest first() end => Test worker  id: 1
FirstParallelUnitTest first() start => Test worker  id: 1
FirstParallelUnitTest first() end => Test worker  id: 1
FirstParallelUnitTest first() start => Test worker  id: 1
FirstParallelUnitTest first() end => Test worker  id: 1
FirstParallelUnitTest first() start => Test worker  id: 1
FirstParallelUnitTest first() end => Test worker  id: 1
FirstParallelUnitTest first() start => Test worker  id: 1
FirstParallelUnitTest first() end => Test worker  id: 1
FirstParallelUnitTest first() start => Test worker  id: 1
FirstParallelUnitTest first() end => Test worker  id: 1
FirstParallelUnitTest first() start => Test worker  id: 1
FirstParallelUnitTest first() end => Test worker  id: 1
```

`thread` `id` does not change, or the order of `start/end` does not change each time.

How can I run this test in parallel and each other test in parallel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`@spock.lang.Execution`](https://spockframework.org/spock/javadoc/2.0/spock/lang/Execution.html) and `org.spockframework.runtime.model.parallel.ExecutionMode` annotations/classes instead of JUnit 5 ones. As an example, your imports might look like this:

```
import org.spockframework.runtime.model.parallel.ExecutionMode
import spock.lang.Execution
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll
```

You should also enable the ["Parallel Execution"](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.3/all_in_one.html#parallel-execution) feature in Spock, e.g. by adding [SpockConfig.groovy](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.3/all_in_one.html#spock-configuration-file) with necessary configs (different options are available, just refer to that page). As an example, your config might look like this:

```
runner {
  parallel {
    enabled true
  }
}
```

I've put this file into the test resources directory (root package). Also, read a note on that page which states:

> JUnit Jupiter also supports parallel execution, both rely on the JUnit Platform implementation, but function independently of each other. If you enable parallel execution in Spock it won’t affect Jupiter and vice versa.

An in general, that ["Parallel Execution"](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.3/all_in_one.html#parallel-execution) article is a good read.

Once I've done the above I'm able to run the test methods in parallel. Here is my output:

```
FirstParallelUnitTest first() start => ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1  id: 17
FirstParallelUnitTest first() start => ForkJoinPool-1-worker-6  id: 22
FirstParallelUnitTest first() start => ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5  id: 20
FirstParallelUnitTest first() end => ForkJoinPool-1-worker-6  id: 22
FirstParallelUnitTest first() end => ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1  id: 17
FirstParallelUnitTest first() end => ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5  id: 20
FirstParallelUnitTest first() start => ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4  id: 21
FirstParallelUnitTest first() start => ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2  id: 18
FirstParallelUnitTest first() end => ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2  id: 18
FirstParallelUnitTest first() end => ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4  id: 21
FirstParallelUnitTest first() start => ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1  id: 17
FirstParallelUnitTest first() start => ForkJoinPool-1-worker-6  id: 22
FirstParallelUnitTest first() start => ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2  id: 18
FirstParallelUnitTest first() start => ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5  id: 20
FirstParallelUnitTest first() start => ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3  id: 19
FirstParallelUnitTest first() end => ForkJoinPool-1-worker-6  id: 22
FirstParallelUnitTest first() end => ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3  id: 19
FirstParallelUnitTest first() end => ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2  id: 18
FirstParallelUnitTest first() end => ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5  id: 20
FirstParallelUnitTest first() end => ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1  id: 17
FirstParallelUnitTest first() start => ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4  id: 21
FirstParallelUnitTest first() end => ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4  id: 21
FirstParallelUnitTest first() start => ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2  id: 18
FirstParallelUnitTest first() end => ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2  id: 18
```

Without those steps my output was sequential as yours.

Comment: I made it work only if I have `SpockConfig.groovy` file in directory `~/.spock`.
When i added this file in project's `src/test` or `src/test/groovy` or `/src/test/groovy/packageName` directory nothing changes.
Where `packageName` is the same root in my opinion as the one in the main code let's say `a.b.c.d.e`. Should this file contain package name like `package a.b.c.d.e` or not ? I tried both versions but it won't work that way. I am not sure what is `root` directory in my case.
`EDIT:` I placed the file in `src/test/resources/SpockConfig.Groovy` and it works.

Comment: Is this an valid option to also run `springboot's` integration tests in parallel that way?

Comment: Also I have noted that when setting `fixed(1)` in `SpockConfig.Groovy` the `IntelliJ IDEA` is saying tests from the question took `121ms` when i change it to `fixed(2)` or more the time is much more like `228ms` - why is that? Should it not be faster?

Comment: @tryingHard `root` means no packages. I also put that file into the `src/test/resources` and it worked. As for spring boot integration tests, why not? It depends on the tests and spring context machinery, etc. But technically, it's possible. About the timing, you mentioned you only have 2 cores and setting `fixed(2)` might be unreasonable and slower in that case. I could test some scenarios a bit later and will let you know the results.

Comment: I think that this test was slower - maybe branch prediction?
On other more complex test i think it was faster.
I have 2 cores but 4 threads - so I guess i have `4` logical units because of that I have `2` threads by default (4-2=2). Now i am thinking about `wiremock` because it is not `thead safe` - I get an error when one test get's an request from another `thread` and can not find `stub`. Adding `traceId` to wiremock won't help, because the `test` request don't have a `header` set. Maybe I should set many wiremocks for each test - but I want to have `1` `Spring context`. Any idea?